# Classic asp include

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, externalizing

I am trying to separate some asp logic out into a separate page.
For now, I am trying to call a simple function.

Here is the simple index page that I am using

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calling a webservice from classic ASP</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
 %>
  <!--#include file="aspFunctions.asp"-->
  <%
  doStuff()
End If
%>
<FORM method=POST name="form1" ID="Form1">
ID:
<INPUT type="text" name="corpId" ID="id" value="050893">
<BR><BR>
<INPUT type="submit" value="GO" name="submit1" ID="Submit1" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is aspfunctions.asp

```
sub doStuff()
    Response.Write("In Do Stuff")
end sub
```

When i hit the submit button on my form i get the below
sub doStuff() Response.Write("In Do Stuff") end sub

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Does anyone have any idea what i could be doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks
Damien
Type mismatch: 'doStuff'

/uat/damien/index.asp, line 15

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`aspfunctions.asp` should be inside tags so the asp is "executed", e.g.

aspfunctions.asp file:

```
<%
sub doStuff()
    Response.Write("In Do Stuff")
end sub
%>
```

Otherwise the asp in `aspfunctions.asp` is just seen as plain-text, so as far as the server is concerned, `doStuff` has never been defined.

Answer (score 8):

You must have the asp functions inside the <% %> tag.

Comment: classic case of another set (or hundred) of eyes seeing what the original developer couldn't...good deal!

Answer (score 5):

You're including the other file within an if statement. This does not mean that it's dynamically included, it's not. It will always be included.

To see this in action try this sample:

```
<%
If 1=0 Then
'We never get here
%>
    <!--#include file="aspFunctions.asp"-->
<%
    dostuff()
End If
dostuff()
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you need no brackets for calls without a return value (untested solution):

```
doStuff
```

Answer (score -2):

Make changes in two places:

1. In aspfunctions.asp write "sub doStuff" instead of `sub doStuff()`
2. Call the function as `doStuff` not `doStuff()`